# Couldn't find Article with 'id'=show

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I know this question may be simple and related to other problems but in my case those solutions are not working, so my question is how to deal with this problem?

While I try to show the article I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show couldn't find
>   article with 'id'=show

I am stucking here

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

Here is my code snippets
My article_controller.rb look like this

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles= Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article= current_user.articles.build
  end

  def create
    @article=current_user.articles.build(@article_params)
    if @article.save
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article=Article.new(article_params)
  end 
end
```

my index.html.erb looks like this

```
<h2>welcome index</h2>

<ul>
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <%= article.titile %>
    <%= article.body %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

my show.html.erb look like this

```
<h2><%= @article.title %></h2>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
```

my Routes look like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root 'articles#index'

  resources :articles

  get 'articles/show'
end
```

Comment: Have you created an article with id = params[:id]?

Comment: How does the link to the article look like?

Comment: this is the next show.html.erb part   <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article), class: 'article_title', id: "article_#{article.id}"  %>
    </li>
  <% end %>    and my routes look like this root 'articles#index'

  resources :articles

Comment: @BharatMane please show your `config/routes.rb` file and the link you're trying to open in browser

Comment: @BharatMane add this information to the question by editing it. And, as nattfodd wrote, include your `config/routes.rb` content.

Comment: Thanks! here I edited routes please check it. And, I am trying to open link in browser is  http://localhost:3000/articles/show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `get 'articles/show'` line from your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Nope, sorry that doesn't working. Actually I tried before that without adding get 'articles/show' but still not working

Comment: please let me now if any extra snippets needed

Comment: @BharatMane ok, so tell me why do you try to open `/articles/show` link? It isn't gonna work. It's not the way `articles#show` path should look like. It should be `/articles/:id`. Where did you get this `/articles/show` from?

Comment: basically I am new to RoR , I am trying to display all list of articles in index page and displaying each articles in show page.    Yes that was my typo even if I try to   get 'articles#show' that's also not working . Thanks!!

Comment: It isn't gonna work either (and it isn't a typo). If you want to display information about specific article, you need to include some information that will enable Rails to identify this article in your URL. So your route should look like `/articles/:id`, where `:id` is your article's id, for example: `/articles/1` (provided, of course, you have Article with id = 1).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I'm using Rails 7 and I only changed the route **show**. Try this:

```
Routes
```

#### --------------------- Routes--------------------

```
get 'articles', to: 'articles#index'
get 'articles/show/:id', to: 'articles#show'
get 'articles/new', to: 'articles#new'
post 'articles/new', to: 'articles#create'*
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'articles#index'

get 'articles/show/:id', to: 'articles#show'

end

Comment: Although this might be the correct answer, you should elaborate a bit and explain what this code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Hey learners here is your answer for the problem you have:-

Add resources :articles in your routes.rb

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).